# Changing the order of params in pagination links

Tags: url, cakephp, pagination

I am using Cakephp to perform a search through sphinx. I wanted to do modify the default structre of pagination links generated by cakephp
For example

From:

```
localhost/search/page:1/key1:google/key2:code
```

To:

```
localhost/search/key1:google/key2:code/page:1
```

I want the page number to appear at the end. Is there a way this can be done?
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you modify the PaginatorHelper.  I would recommend that you extend it and load it when Cake launches so that you dont modify the Cake file in cake/libs...

Then, wherever you want the output URL to be printed w/ the page number at the end, you'll need to modify the PaginatorHelper... I'd suggest you search for the page/# key/value pair.  If you find it, remove it, then append it to the end of the string.  Then return that value.

Edit: link to PaginatorHelper in the API - http://api.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper

Comment: Good answer, but it seems like an awful lot of work for very little benefit... :-)